# Book sort program

Tags: java, swing, sorting, event-handling, radio-button

In this program I am trying to initialize an array of book objects and have them displayed in a JPanel that will allow them to be sorted based on which radio button is selected by the user.

I have not finished some of the back-end sorting constructors but I am trying to get through the full functionality first. Here is my object class that has all the getters/setters:

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class SchoolTextBook {

private String author;
private String title;
private int pageCount;
private String ISBN;
private double price;

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
    }
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
    }

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    }

public int getPageCount() {
    return pageCount;
}
public void setPageCount(int pageCount) {
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
}

public String getISBN() {
    return ISBN;
}
public void setISBN(String iSBN) {
    ISBN = iSBN;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public static Comparator<SchoolTextBook> BookAuthorComparator 
                    = new Comparator<SchoolTextBook>() {

    public int compare(SchoolTextBook book1, SchoolTextBook book2) {

        String bookName1 = book1.getAuthor().toUpperCase();
        String bookName2 = book2.getAuthor().toUpperCase();

        //ascending order
        return bookName1.compareTo(bookName2);

    }

};

public static Comparator<SchoolTextBook> BookTitleComparator 
                    = new Comparator<SchoolTextBook>() {

    public int compare(SchoolTextBook book1, SchoolTextBook book2) {

        String bookName1 = book1.getTitle().toUpperCase();
        String bookName2 = book2.getTitle().toUpperCase();

        //ascending order
        return bookName1.compareTo(bookName2);

    }

};
}
```

And here is my sort class that initializes the objects and sets their attributes(this class will also display the gui... I think):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SchoolTextBookSort {

public static String show() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
    sb.append("<html><table><tr><td>Item</td><td>Price</td><td>Quantity</td><td></td>Priority</tr>");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("hi").append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("hi").append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("hi").append("</td>");
    sb.append("<td>").append("hi").append("</td>");
    sb.append("</tr></table></html>");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });

    SchoolTextBook[] theBooks = new SchoolTextBook[5];

    theBooks[0] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[1] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[2] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[3] = new SchoolTextBook();
    theBooks[4] = new SchoolTextBook();

    theBooks[0].setAuthor("Ernest Hemingway");
    theBooks[1].setAuthor("Mark Twain");
    theBooks[2].setAuthor("William Shakespeare");
    theBooks[3].setAuthor("Stephen King");
    theBooks[4].setAuthor("William Faulkner");

    theBooks[0].setTitle("A Farewell to Arms");
    theBooks[1].setTitle("The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn");
    theBooks[2].setTitle("Hamlet");
    theBooks[3].setTitle("Salem's Lot");
    theBooks[4].setTitle("The Sound and the Fury");

    theBooks[0].setPageCount(332);
    theBooks[1].setPageCount(320);
    theBooks[2].setPageCount(196);
    theBooks[3].setPageCount(439);
    theBooks[4].setPageCount(326);

    theBooks[0].setISBN("0099910101");
    theBooks[1].setISBN("0142437174");
    theBooks[2].setISBN("0521618746");
    theBooks[3].setISBN("0450031063");
    theBooks[4].setISBN("0679732241");

    theBooks[0].setPrice(5.99);
    theBooks[1].setPrice(7.60);
    theBooks[2].setPrice(9.41);
    theBooks[3].setPrice(16.56);
    theBooks[4].setPrice(9.60);     

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,   theBooks[0].getAuthor() + " - " + theBooks[0].getTitle() + " - " 
                                        + theBooks[0].getISBN() + " - " + theBooks[0].getPageCount() + " - "
                                        + theBooks[0].getPrice() + "\n" 
                                        + theBooks[1].getAuthor() + " - " + theBooks[1].getTitle() + " - " 
                                        + theBooks[1].getISBN() + " - " + theBooks[1].getPageCount() + " - "
                                        + theBooks[1].getPrice() + "\n"
                                        + theBooks[2].getAuthor() + " - " + theBooks[2].getTitle() + " - " 
                                        + theBooks[2].getISBN() + " - " + theBooks[2].getPageCount() + " - "
                                        + theBooks[2].getPrice() + "\n"
                                        + theBooks[3].getAuthor() + " - " + theBooks[3].getTitle() + " - " 
                                        + theBooks[3].getISBN() + " - " + theBooks[3].getPageCount() + " - "
                                        + theBooks[3].getPrice() + "\n"
                                        + theBooks[4].getAuthor() + " - " + theBooks[4].getTitle() + " - " 
                                        + theBooks[4].getISBN() + " - " + theBooks[4].getPageCount() + " - "
                                        + theBooks[4].getPrice());



    Arrays.sort(theBooks, SchoolTextBook.BookAuthorComparator);


    for(int i = 0; i < theBooks.length; i++) {

    }


}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Book Sorting");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new RadioButtonDisplay();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And my last class that has the custom coding for the radio buttons that will update the GUI with the sorted information. (which will I still need to enter into the show() method of sort class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RadioButtonDisplay extends JPanel
                            implements ActionListener {
String authorString = "Author";
String titleString = "Title";
String priceString = "Price";
String pageCountString = "Page Count";

JLabel sortedArray;

public RadioButtonDisplay() {

    JRadioButton authorButton = new JRadioButton(authorString);
    authorButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    authorButton.setActionCommand(authorString);

    JRadioButton titleButton = new JRadioButton(titleString);
    titleButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    titleButton.setActionCommand(titleString);

    JRadioButton priceButton = new JRadioButton(priceString);
    priceButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    priceButton.setActionCommand(priceString);

    JRadioButton pageCountButton = new JRadioButton(pageCountString);
    pageCountButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    pageCountButton.setActionCommand(pageCountString);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(authorButton);
    group.add(titleButton);
    group.add(priceButton);
    group.add(pageCountButton);

    authorButton.addActionListener(this);
    titleButton.addActionListener(this);
    priceButton.addActionListener(this);
    pageCountButton.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    radioPanel.add(authorButton);
    radioPanel.add(titleButton);
    radioPanel.add(priceButton);
    radioPanel.add(pageCountButton);

    add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    add(sortedArray, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sortedArray.setText(SchoolTextBookSort.show());e.getActionCommand();

}
}
```

I am having trouble getting the GUI to display and also I don't think the code is correct on the event-handling. (I have still yet to implement the sorting to the particular radio buttons.)

Any help/insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"I am having trouble.."*  ..forming a question?  Do you have a (clear, specific) question?

Comment: You should restrict your questions to a single question at a time. Now, by saying "I am having trouble getting the GUI to display" do you mean that some element is being displayed improperly, or is your GUI not rendering at all?

Comment: It is not rendering at all... I do not know where my problem is located...

Answer (score 1):

> It is not rendering at all...

Well write the code one step at a time. The sorting is irrelevant so get rid of all that code.

The the first step is to get the GUI components displayed. Then the next step is to work on the sorting. Keep the code simple and do one step at a time. It is easier to debug that way.

Not sure if it is the problem, but by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. Your code is assuming a BorderLayout:

```
add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
add(sortedArray, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Not sure if it will make a difference (since a FlowLayout probably just ignores the constraint anyway) but you should be using:

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
add(sortedArray, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also, a JPanel is opaque by default so the following code is not needed:

```
//newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
```